# HTTPUrlConnection Issues on Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am facing an interesting problem with HTTPUrlConnection on Android.
Here are the steps
1. Create a new HTTPUrlConnection  with a particular url say URL
2. Now I change the APN settings on device level
3. Now I create another HTTPUrlConnection  with the same URL.
When trying to read input steam after step 3, connection times-out.

Another interesting thing is **When I change the URL in step 3 everything seems to work fine**

One reason I can think of can be Android somehow keeps previous connection alive and returns me the same connection in step 3 and since the APN is changed, that connection is no more valid.

**Any Insights in this will be greatly appreciated.**

Thanks,
Manan

Answer (score 1):

> One reason I can think of can be Android somehow keeps previous connection alive and returns me the same connection in step 3 and since the APN is changed, that connection is no more valid.

That is a very distinct possibility. Android added keep-alive support to `HttpUrlConnection`. Normally, APN settings don't change (AFAIK), so this may not be a big problem. However, you can disable keep-alive via `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");`, according to [this Android Developer Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).